# Sitecore TDS package Item deploy order

Tags: tds

I am using TDS version "6.0.0.34" and I have TDS project that contains templates and branches , inside the branches folder those templates are used.
while deployment of TDS package I found that some fields in the templates are deployed after the branch deployment which cause loss in the branch data.

Is there any way to handle this dependency or should I split this TDS?

Comment: Check the tds item deployment properties and make sure it is set to always update. That should address this.

Comment: The issue is that the branch is created and not all the fields of the template are created so the field is redeployed  and overwrite the changes in the branch